# Running a page twice at same time with php

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

$user = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "code";
mysql_connect("localhost", $user, $password);
mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database");

// check if a running process
$query = mysql_query("select * from cats where update_status = 1");
$connections = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($connections >= 1) {
    die("overload");
}


mysql_query("update cats set update_status = 1 where id = 4");

// working....
sleep(50);

mysql_query("update cats set update_status = 0 where id = 4");

mysql_close();
```

The problem was that when I called this page one time and, 
within the sleep function time I opened a new tab of the same page, the page continue executing sleep function.
**It should give "OVERLOAD" ?**

NOTE: if I copy this code to new page (example test.php) and load it within the sleep time it works

Comment: Can I ask why you need to do this?

Comment: I use cron job to call this page and I want to do one update process per time

Comment: I don't really think script file name should effect how that code will be executed

Comment: that I believe,but i have tried more methods and still have the same problem

Comment: add `or die("error")` to the `mysql_query` statements.  They may not have been completed as expected.

Comment: have you though of using `flock` ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php

Comment: Is the update successful? Meaning ... is there an id = 4 ?

Comment: there is id have value 4, the update was executed successfully, I think that flock is not useful for me